# Getting number of likes for a user in all his posts using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, social-media-like

Hi I want to build a leader board that will rank users based on the likes they have accumulated in all their posts.

My database for Posts

```
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  imageURL: {
    type: [String],
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
  },
  likes: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      },
    },
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  }
```

My database for user:

```
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
```

I have tried various queries and aggregation functions but I am not able to get the right solution for that. Is there another way to do get the list.
I want to get a list of users and total likes they got in all their posts combined. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      user: 1,
      numberOfLikes: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $isArray: "$likes"
          },
          then: {
            $size: "$likes"
          },
          else: "NA"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can find demo of this query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cj3889kLXId)

Answer (score 0):

I recently have the same scenario, here's how I solved it:

I created 3 different Models. Users, Posts, Likes.
The Post model will be:

```
 user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  imageURL: {
    type: [String],
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  }
```

The Likes model:

```
postId: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  required: true
},
userId: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  required: true
},
likedBy: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User',
  required: true,
}
```

1. While fetching the post, you can use aggregate function and fetch the likes with the post [as
   shown here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).
2. If you want to fetch the number of likes the user has received, You can do it easily by: `Like.find({userId}).countDocuments()`

Avoid using arrays in such cases.
Because there can be no limit for user likes.
If your Application grows, managing likes this way would be a nightmare.

Comment: I actually kinda solved it, though not proud of the solution

I added 2 more fields in profile model namely numberPosts and likes.
And in the route of like, dislike,create / delete post I have called the profile model and updated every time.

Comment: Thats cool, but don't use likes as an array in Post schema, use separate model of Like instead. :)

Comment: Ha I'll give it a go. Thanks